# Sum over another column returning 'col should be column error'

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to add a new column where by it shows the sum of a double (things to sum column) based on the respective ID in the ID column. this however is currently throwing the 'col should be column error'

```
df = df.withColumn('sum_column', (df.groupBy('id').agg({'thing_to_sum': 'sum'})))
```

Example Data Set:

```html
| id | thing_to_sum | sum_column |
|----|--------------|------------
| 1  | 5            | 7          |
| 1  | 2            | 7          |
| 2  | 4            | 4          |
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Also any reference on the most efficient way to do this would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register any `DataFrame` as a temporary table to query it via `SQLContext.sql`.

```
myValues = [(1,5),(1,2),(2,4),(2,3),(2,1)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(myValues,['id','thing_to_sum'])
df.show()
+---+------------+
| id|thing_to_sum|
+---+------------+
|  1|           5|
|  1|           2|
|  2|           4|
|  2|           3|
|  2|           1|
+---+------------+
df.registerTempTable('table_view')
df1=sqlContext.sql(
    'select id, thing_to_sum, sum(thing_to_sum) over (partition by id) as sum_column from table_view'
)
df1.show()
+---+------------+----------+
| id|thing_to_sum|sum_column|
+---+------------+----------+
|  1|           5|         7|
|  1|           2|         7|
|  2|           4|         8|
|  2|           3|         8|
|  2|           1|         8|
+---+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Comment: Pleasure Sir :)

Answer (score 1):

Think i found the solution to my own question but advice would still be appreciated:

```
sum_calc = F.sum(df.thing_to_sum).over(Window.partitionBy("id"))
df = df.withColumn("sum_column", sum_calc)
```